# XML Transformation from Java Code

Tags: java, xslt

I am doing transformation of an XML File using XSL through Java code. I used [this](http://www.roseindia.net/xml/developing-xslt-transformer.shtml) tutorial for the same. Now the problem is that the output file is created but it has no contents in it. I am also adding the code snippet. Kindly check it and tell me what am I missing :

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    System.out.println("In transform");
    File temp = new File(xslFile);
    if(temp.exists()){
        System.out.println("File found");
    }
    StreamSource xsl = new StreamSource(temp); 
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);


    temp = new File(xmlFile);
    if(temp.exists()){
        System.out.println("Found Again!!");
    }
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(temp);

    temp = new File(outputFile);
    if(temp.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("New File Created");
    }
    StreamResult output = new StreamResult(temp);

    transformer.transform(xml, output);
```

Here, the xslFile, xmlFile and outputFile are string and passed as parameters to the method.

Comment: Here the outputFile is an HTML file.

Comment: Your Java code looks okay. The problem is probably with the stylesheet itself. Could you provide the input XML and XSLT?

Comment: Actually the problem was that it took too long time at the transformation step. i.e. while executing the following code        :- transformer.transform(xml,output). However, the code works fine and creates the file with desired content. But I have faced a similar problem even while XML Parsing that it takes too long to process. My system is not slow as such but could there be some specific reason for this time lag?

Comment: Since the processing took too long I used to terminate the program and check the contents of the file which was already created into the current working directory. When I found the contents empty, I doubted the code. However, it is correct. Thank you!

Comment: I checked the time and found that code is taking 2 minutes and 15 seconds to transform 1 KB of XML using 1 KB of XSL to generate 1 KB of html file. Now that is not acceptable for my system with 3 GB RAM and 3 GHz AMD processor!

Comment: XSLT can be considered a programming language and as such is open to code optimization. But 2 minutes does seem rather outrageous. XSLT in Java ought to be pretty fast, whether the stylesheet is interpreted or compiled. Could you do 2 things: provide the XSLT, and put `System.out.println(factory.getClass().getCanonicalName());` in your code and tell us what that outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare three different variables, one for each file. Code will look clearer and you most likely will avoid some unexpected behaviour, as you don't know how is `Transformer` using those three references.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The code may be cleaner but it would never have effect on execution since he's assigning a new File instance to `temp` every time before using it to construct a Source or Result.